# Конвертор валюты в таблице

Tags: javascript, php

Необходимо решить не самую сложную задачку.
Есть таблица Название-Стоимость.
В графе стоимость цены указаны в рублях.
Необходимо прикрутить к таблице 2 кнопки **EUR, USD**, при нажатии на которые скрипт получает данные курса этих валют из ЦБ РФ и конвертирует значения в таблице.
Парсить курс валют из API цб у меня получается, но реализовать функцию с конвертацией никак нет.
Массивы с валютыми ЦБ
[json](https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js)
[xml](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp)

Comment: Не получается умножить одно число на другое??

Comment: Не получается разделить имеющееся число в таблице на  динамическое число из массива.(Курс меняется каждый день) Не совсем понимаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на SO!

Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, в чем именно ваша проблема. JavaScript выполняется при каждой загрузке страницы, ему не важно изменился ли курс валют или нет, он всегда будет использовать актуальный, если вы таковой ему передадите.

Полагаю, такое поведение вы ожидали увидеть?

```js
//Предположим, вы уже получили данные, я же их просто их скопирую.
let json = `{
    "Date": "2021-01-21T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousDate": "2021-01-20T11:30:00+03:00",
    "PreviousURL": "\/\/www.cbr-xml-daily.ru\/archive\/2021\/01\/20\/daily_json.js",
    "Timestamp": "2021-01-20T14:00:00+03:00",
    "Valute": {
        "AUD": {
            "ID": "R01010",
            "NumCode": "036",
            "CharCode": "AUD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
            "Value": 56.7401,
            "Previous": 56.893
        },
        "AZN": {
            "ID": "R01020A",
            "NumCode": "944",
            "CharCode": "AZN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
            "Value": 43.1754,
            "Previous": 43.3928
        },
        "GBP": {
            "ID": "R01035",
            "NumCode": "826",
            "CharCode": "GBP",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
            "Value": 100.2836,
            "Previous": 100.2282
        },
        "AMD": {
            "ID": "R01060",
            "NumCode": "051",
            "CharCode": "AMD",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Армянских драмов",
            "Value": 14.0486,
            "Previous": 14.1183
        },
        "BYN": {
            "ID": "R01090B",
            "NumCode": "933",
            "CharCode": "BYN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Белорусский рубль",
            "Value": 28.9084,
            "Previous": 28.9274
        },
        "BGN": {
            "ID": "R01100",
            "NumCode": "975",
            "CharCode": "BGN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Болгарский лев",
            "Value": 45.5423,
            "Previous": 45.6667
        },
        "BRL": {
            "ID": "R01115",
            "NumCode": "986",
            "CharCode": "BRL",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Бразильский реал",
            "Value": 13.6905,
            "Previous": 13.9202
        },
        "HUF": {
            "ID": "R01135",
            "NumCode": "348",
            "CharCode": "HUF",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Венгерских форинтов",
            "Value": 24.9227,
            "Previous": 24.8611
        },
        "HKD": {
            "ID": "R01200",
            "NumCode": "344",
            "CharCode": "HKD",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Гонконгских долларов",
            "Value": 94.6309,
            "Previous": 95.1024
        },
        "DKK": {
            "ID": "R01215",
            "NumCode": "208",
            "CharCode": "DKK",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Датская крона",
            "Value": 11.9724,
            "Previous": 12.0078
        },
        "USD": {
            "ID": "R01235",
            "NumCode": "840",
            "CharCode": "USD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Доллар США",
            "Value": 73.355,
            "Previous": 73.7243
        },
        "EUR": {
            "ID": "R01239",
            "NumCode": "978",
            "CharCode": "EUR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Евро",
            "Value": 89.1483,
            "Previous": 89.2064
        },
        "INR": {
            "ID": "R01270",
            "NumCode": "356",
            "CharCode": "INR",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Индийских рупий",
            "Value": 10.0392,
            "Previous": 10.0674
        },
        "KZT": {
            "ID": "R01335",
            "NumCode": "398",
            "CharCode": "KZT",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Казахстанских тенге",
            "Value": 17.5272,
            "Previous": 17.558
        },
        "CAD": {
            "ID": "R01350",
            "NumCode": "124",
            "CharCode": "CAD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Канадский доллар",
            "Value": 57.778,
            "Previous": 57.9093
        },
        "KGS": {
            "ID": "R01370",
            "NumCode": "417",
            "CharCode": "KGS",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Киргизских сомов",
            "Value": 86.4766,
            "Previous": 87.0417
        },
        "CNY": {
            "ID": "R01375",
            "NumCode": "156",
            "CharCode": "CNY",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Китайский юань",
            "Value": 11.3416,
            "Previous": 11.3628
        },
        "MDL": {
            "ID": "R01500",
            "NumCode": "498",
            "CharCode": "MDL",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Молдавских леев",
            "Value": 42.1338,
            "Previous": 42.5414
        },
        "NOK": {
            "ID": "R01535",
            "NumCode": "578",
            "CharCode": "NOK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Норвежских крон",
            "Value": 86.2391,
            "Previous": 86.2817
        },
        "PLN": {
            "ID": "R01565",
            "NumCode": "985",
            "CharCode": "PLN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Польский злотый",
            "Value": 19.6794,
            "Previous": 19.7071
        },
        "RON": {
            "ID": "R01585F",
            "NumCode": "946",
            "CharCode": "RON",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Румынский лей",
            "Value": 18.273,
            "Previous": 18.3243
        },
        "XDR": {
            "ID": "R01589",
            "NumCode": "960",
            "CharCode": "XDR",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "СДР (специальные права заимствования)",
            "Value": 105.6239,
            "Previous": 106.1925
        },
        "SGD": {
            "ID": "R01625",
            "NumCode": "702",
            "CharCode": "SGD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Сингапурский доллар",
            "Value": 55.3247,
            "Previous": 55.4485
        },
        "TJS": {
            "ID": "R01670",
            "NumCode": "972",
            "CharCode": "TJS",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Таджикских сомони",
            "Value": 64.3747,
            "Previous": 64.6988
        },
        "TRY": {
            "ID": "R01700J",
            "NumCode": "949",
            "CharCode": "TRY",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Турецких лир",
            "Value": 98.52,
            "Previous": 98.7864
        },
        "TMT": {
            "ID": "R01710A",
            "NumCode": "934",
            "CharCode": "TMT",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Новый туркменский манат",
            "Value": 20.9886,
            "Previous": 21.0942
        },
        "UZS": {
            "ID": "R01717",
            "NumCode": "860",
            "CharCode": "UZS",
            "Nominal": 10000,
            "Name": "Узбекских сумов",
            "Value": 69.8565,
            "Previous": 70.2082
        },
        "UAH": {
            "ID": "R01720",
            "NumCode": "980",
            "CharCode": "UAH",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Украинских гривен",
            "Value": 26.054,
            "Previous": 26.1531
        },
        "CZK": {
            "ID": "R01760",
            "NumCode": "203",
            "CharCode": "CZK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Чешских крон",
            "Value": 34.098,
            "Previous": 34.1854
        },
        "SEK": {
            "ID": "R01770",
            "NumCode": "752",
            "CharCode": "SEK",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Шведских крон",
            "Value": 87.8871,
            "Previous": 88.2081
        },
        "CHF": {
            "ID": "R01775",
            "NumCode": "756",
            "CharCode": "CHF",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Швейцарский франк",
            "Value": 82.6628,
            "Previous": 82.9295
        },
        "ZAR": {
            "ID": "R01810",
            "NumCode": "710",
            "CharCode": "ZAR",
            "Nominal": 10,
            "Name": "Южноафриканских рэндов",
            "Value": 49.306,
            "Previous": 48.8674
        },
        "KRW": {
            "ID": "R01815",
            "NumCode": "410",
            "CharCode": "KRW",
            "Nominal": 1000,
            "Name": "Вон Республики Корея",
            "Value": 66.5995,
            "Previous": 66.8007
        },
        "JPY": {
            "ID": "R01820",
            "NumCode": "392",
            "CharCode": "JPY",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Японских иен",
            "Value": 70.7002,
            "Previous": 70.8922
        }
    }
}`;

let usdBtn = document.querySelector('.usd'),
    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

usdBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('.price_cell').forEach(item=>{
    item.textContent = +item.textContent * parsedJSON.Valute.USD.Value;
  })
})
```

```css
.table{
  width: 300px;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%
}
.cell{
  width: 50%
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Название
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Стоимость
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Товар 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell price_cell">
      150
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      Товар 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell price_cell">
      900
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="usd">usd</button>
```